# Dynamically creating pages in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently making a plugin that is supposed to display information for a person's profile page. I know how to make subpages in the following way.

https://mywebsite.com/page?page_name=mypage_name

On the load of the page, I would use php to get the variable then dynamically load the page from there. I don't think that the url is too pretty though. I rather have it look like the following.

https://mywebsite.com/page/mypage

Would I have to make a page in wordpress for each person or is there a way to dynamically create pages based off the url? Would there be a way to do the first way using $_GET then change the url to say what I want?

Thanks!

edit 1: I'm not asking how to change permalinks for the entire site, not at all. I'm asking how to do it in a plugin for a certain set of pages.

Comment: If you are using WordPress, there are ways to change the permalinks.

Comment: yeah, but that is if I'm the user of the wordpress. I'm creating a plugin that the site would use where your users could enter information, and it would be displayed on their own page. So, I'm trying to figure out if I need to make one page that everyone goes to, just uses different ids. OR do I create one page for each person and it goes to that page. Or if there's a way to do it the first way, but have it look like the second way.